# Add a custom product page in spartacus

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I need to create a new custom PDP page on my Hybris Storefront and URL should be

```
{siteurl}/asset/{assetCode}
```

I have created a custom product detail page in hybris using the impexes

```
INSERT_UPDATE ProductPage; uid[unique=true]; name          ; masterTemplate(uid, $contentCV); defaultPage; approvalStatus(code)[default='approved']; $contentCV[unique=true]
                         ; assetDetails    ; Asset Details ; AssetDetailsPageTemplate       ; false      ;
```

I am not expert in Spartacus.
How do I map this custom PDP in the Spartacus side.
Can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hybris has product based page functionality. You don't need a custom endpoint for this. Spartacus makes backend call with product code to find a page. You can add restriction to your page based on your product. Check the network activity for below endpoint.

> /cms/pages?pageType=ProductPage&code=YOUR_PRODUCT

You can also add custom endpoint but it requires a lot of effort.

Comment: You are right ..But as i mentioned i need the product page routing should be{siteurl}/asset/{assetCode}..How do i achieve it